# Is "... we can already make..." grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/5nqlseLy2nw?t=85)

> we can already make two observations.

it seems that `already` is used for perfect tense, so is this expression here grammatical?

Comment: What about this is leading you to suspect that it might not be grammatical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Already" is not only used with perfect tenses:

> I already play tennis.
>
> I already saw that film  (have seen would have the same meaning)
>
> By Monday I will already be in Japan.

When a verb phrase indicates a state, not an action, you often don't need a perfect tense. The modal verb "can" indicates a state, so it is idiomatic to say

> We can already make two observations

instead of

> We can already have made two observations (grammatically correct, but not a common expression)

or

> I can already speak Chinese. (correct)
>
> I can already have spoken Chinese (odd to the point of being wrong)